# Why do I keep getting Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object with this code

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include('db_conx.php');
$username= $_POST ['username'];
$password= $_POST ['password'];
//Test:
echo "<h1>Username: $username</h1>";
echo "<h1>Password: $password</h1>";
$mysqli=new mysqli       
    ('localhost','1800758_robbie','mypassword', '1800758_robbie');
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM  
    1800758_robbie.users3 WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username,$password);
$stm->execute();
$stmt-> store_result();
$res=$stmt->num_rows();
if($res == 1) {echo "You have successfully logged in.";}else{echo " the 
    username and password you've supplied is not valid.";}
?>
```

I have tried reading several other posts but none match this code. I am so lost as to why I keep getting this error message. All I want to do is create a succesful login page for a forum. BTW I have all my login information correct on my end.

Comment: There's no object named `$conn` anywhere in your code, but you're trying to call `$conn->prepare()`

Comment: im self teaching code what is wrong with the bind parameter part i keep getting the same error message i changed the $conn to $mysqli and that seemed to solve that